# where is the main function of my app?

Tags: asp.net, .net

I'm first time working on a .NET app, which consists of two controllers / views: login.aspx and default.aspx. I would like to add a background worker, which should start as soon as the application is executed, but I have no idea where to find the main function or where to add background worker initialization code?

Here is my current project structure:
http://cl.ly/image/2S2o200w0D2t

Thanks

Comment: See [Background Processes in ASP.NET Web Forms](http://chsakell.com/2013/07/20/background-processes-in-asp-net-web-forms/), [How to run Background Tasks in ASP.NET](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it, cause .NET application is a DLL library actually.

For background worker you should create the separate project, f.e. console application or a Windows service.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET doesn't have the notion of "background workers", however you should look at the Global.asax file which can contain several methods such as Application_Start which runs when the application is started.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1xaas8a2%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Further Reading including what functions are available:

http://www.techrepublic.com/article/working-with-the-aspnet-globalasax-file/

Answer (score 0):

Background worker and main method are related to WIN forms and not WEB forms. 
If you want the first time the application runs, Application_Start in the Global.asax can be used.
If its for a particular page, use Page_Load.
Then add threads separately.